# Monotouch Read how much RAM is left on an iPad

Tags: xamarin.ios

Using Monotouch, or Objective-C, how do I tell how much RAM is left on an iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to get the amount of RAM available.

You can handle low memory warnings by subscribing to an event.

In your "Main.cs"

```
 public override void ReceiveMemoryWarning(UIApplication application)
 {
   // Do what you want to free memory
 }
```

Not sure if this helps but given the lack of answers it may prove helpful.