# How much memory am I allowed to allocate in Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

The question says it all - I'd like to know how much memory am I allowed to allocate before my app will eventually be killed by iOS. This is assuming that I still hold references to that memory, so it will not be GC'd.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 4):

You can allocate as much as you want until you receive a memory warning. There is no limit but general comments i have read the mark to be around 3Mb. :-)

Each view controller gets the message `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` which is when you need to dealloc cached images etc to free the memory before you app gets terminated by the OS. In case you program optimally you should be able to do so with handling the memory warning.

---

The same applies to monotouch as the method to override would be

```
public override void ReceiveMemoryWarning(UIApplication application)
```

according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205722/monotouch-read-how-much-ram-is-left-on-an-ipad).

Comment: It depends on your device... I know on the iPhone 4 I've been able to successfully allocate 20-30mb of memory and the app still run okay (obviously I'm not recommending people do so but I was just trying to push it!)

Comment: Yup but on the 2nd gen devices it starts crying for something around 3 mb.

Comment: I have no idea where you got that number 3 megabytes, I routinely allocate more than that.   I believe the rule was you can use about half the system memory for your app, so whatever that is on your device.

Comment: On the 2nd gen device using instruments i had found out that number multiple but then its not a number which is mentioned in specs. So it depends on that device.